# Match several results with same conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

The aim of my workbook is to show result from a spreadsheet, after applying filters.

[image]

In this example,
I get my spreadsheet in range `A1:C13`,

in column E, thanks to the Yellow formula,
It shows every Done date by unsorted.

The problem is that I want to show relative Name in column F. But there is some equals dates for different names,

My reflex where to do an Index Match, but it can't show when there is several results from the same conditions.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check out this [link](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-multiple-matches-into-separate-columns) and let us know if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to include the Name column in the output:

```
=SORT(FILTER(Table2[[Date]:[Name]],Table2[Statut]=E1),1,-1)
```

[image]

---

If your data is not right next to each other and you do not want the middle columns to show in your output then we use the same formula wrapped in INDEX to return the correct column of the array:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Table2[[Date]:[Name]],Table2[Statut]=F1),1,-1),0,1)
```

And

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Table2[[Date]:[Name]],Table2[Statut]=F1),1,-1),0,3)
```

Where the ending `,1` in the first formula refers to the relative column in the referred to range of the date, and the `,3` in the second refers to the relative column in the referred to range of the Name

[image]

Comment: TY, it was exactly was I looking for, to know if we can show the next column in the same formula. ty again !

Comment: But it doesn't sort by descending for the second option (=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(Table2[[Date]:[Name]],Table2[Statut]=F1),1,-1),0,1)), I Don't know why...

Comment: Not sure, as you can see by my photos it sorts for me.